# Consultation about ping to another computer in Windows-Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, ping

Using C# is it possible to send a ping from a device running Windows Mobile to another computer?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built into the Compact Framework.

[OpenNETCFs SDF](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx) contains the [ping class](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/7555257b-b797-37d3-ff61-4e90f731be99.htm). It's located under the [OpenNETCF.Net.NetworkInformation](http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/) namespace. Check out the link to OpenNETCF SDF to see the licensing options (including the Community 
Edition which [seems to be free to use](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/Licenses.aspx) as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use OpenNetCF, you can do it like shown in this example:

http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2014/08/29/mobile-development-pingng-the-next-generation-ping/#more-1965

EDIT: Sorry, this one uses also OpenNetCf, but it is a nice example how to achieve a ping-tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also P/Invoke [`IcmpSendEcho`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917460.aspx#) if you want to send a ping without any 3rd party libraries.